# kafka topics and partitions decisions

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to understand something about kafka:

1. When I have a single kafka broker on a single host - is there any sense to have it have more than one partition for the topics? I means even if my data can be distinguished with some key (say tenant id) - what is the benefit of doing it on a single kafka broker? does this give any parallelism , if so how?
2. When a key is used, is this means that each key is mapped to a given partition? Does the number of partitions for a topic must be equal to the number of possible values for the key I specified? OR is this just a hash and so the number of partitions doesnt have to be equal?
3. From what I read, topics are created due to types of messages to be places in kafka. But in my case, i have 2 topics I have created since I have 2 types of consumption: one for reading one by one message. the second in case of a bulk of messages comes into the queue (application reasons) and then it is being entered into the second topic. Is that a good design although the messages type is the same? any other practice for such a scansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, it definitely makes sense to have more than one partition for a topic even when you have a single Kafka broker. A scenario when you can benefit from this is pretty simple:

   - you need to guarantee in-order processing by tenant id
   - processing logic for each message is rather complex and takes some time. Especially the case when the Kafka message itself is simple, but the logic behind processing this message takes time (simple example - message is an URL, and the processing logic is downloading the file from there and doing some processing)

Given these 2 conditions you may get into a situation where one consumer is not able to keep up processing all the messages if all the data goes to a single partition. Remember, you can process one partition with exactly one consumer (well, you can use 2 consumers if using different consumer groups, but that's not your case), so you'll start getting behind over time. But if you have more than one partition you'll either be able to use one consumer and process data in parallel (this could help to speed things up in some cases) or just add more consumers.

2. By default, Kafka uses hash-based partitioning. This is configurable by providing a custom Partitioner, for example you can use random partitioning if you don't care what partition your message ends up in.
3. It's totally up to you what purposes you have topics for

UPD, answers to questions in the comment:

1. Adding more consumers is usually done for adding more computing power, not for achieving desired parallelism. To add parallelism add partitions. Most consumer implementations process different partitions on different threads, so if you have enough computing power, you might just have a single consumer processing multiple partitions in parallel. Then, if you start bumping into situations where one consumer is not enough, you just add more consumers.
2. When you create a topic you just specify the number of partitions (and replication factor for this topic, but that's a different thing). The key and partition to send is completely up to producer. In fact, you could configure your producer to use random partitioner and it won't even care about keys, just pick the partition randomly. There's no direct relation between key -> partition, it's just convenient to benefit from having things setup like this.
3. Can you elaborate on this one? Not sure I understand this, but I guess your question is whether you can send just a value and Kafka will infer a key somehow itself. If so, then the answer is no - Kafka does not apply any transformation to messages and stores them as is, so if you want your message to contain a key, the producer must explicitly send the key.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed answer. Several more questions to clarify: 1. in the sample you gave in your first answer. if i have many partitions for parallelism purposes, So i cab have many consumers in the same group that reads from those partitions? is that what you means or the same consumer can be multi threaded and hence read more?                        2. When I create a topic I configure it with both the partition number and the key? or the key is up to producer to send? 3. Can the message itself can contains the key and kafka will know to extract it from the JSON?

Comment: Hi few more questions:1. how do you tell the producer to have a random key that matched one of the partitions? 2. If you want to increase the number of partitions in an existing topic is this possible?

Comment: And - if no key is there - then kafka is just doing it randomly?